# Hardness of LWE with Uniform Secrets and Error Distributions

Tags: post-quantum-cryptography, lattice-crypto, lwe

I have seen various papers discussing the security of the Learning with Errors problem with very small uniform secrets and errors but I have not found any papers on the general LWE problem with uniform secrets and errors within (-b,b) range where b < the LWE modulus q but not so small as to be binary or ternary.  Is there a costing for the LWE problem for bounded secrets and errors when they are chosen from a uniform distribution?